# Prove inequality $x, y, z>0$ and $(x-2)(y-2)(z-2) \ge xyz-2$ $\sum{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^5+y^3+z}}}\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{x+y+z}}$

Tags: inequality

$x, y, z>0$ and $(x-2)(y-2)(z-2) \ge xyz-2$
Prove that
$$\sum{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^5+y^3+z}}}\le\frac{3}{\sqrt{x+y+z}}$$

Let's look at the solution of the inequality. Interestingly, I couldn’t find the idea. I couldn’t use the odd levels.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? How far did you get? Where are you stuck? This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context. Please respond by **editing the question** body. Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Please show your attempt. Someone will give a solution after that.